# Minimize fitting function of two variables

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I want to find the best fitting for a polynomial function of two variables. Here are parts of the code:

```
def polynom(x):
    return a*x[:,0] + b*x[:,1] + c

def polynom_try():
    errors = []
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(polynom, X_train, y_train)
    error = mean_squared_error(y_test, polynom(X_test, *popt))
    errors.append(error)
    print(popt)
    print(np.mean(np.array(errors)))
    return np.mean(np.array(errors))

X = list(zip(x1, x2))
X = np.array(X)
# y is 1D array
...
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
random_state=0)
...
x = [0, 0, 0]
opt = minimize(polynom_try, x0=x, method="TNC")
a, b, c = opt.x
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to get the parameters of the polynomial - popt. And not sure how correctly provide x for x0.

link https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html provides an example how to get optimized parameters:

```
x0 = [1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
res.x
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Comment: **1.** You mix `curve_fit` and `minimize`, but only one of them is needed, usually. **2.** Do not use the test set to optimize the fit. **3.** If any of the previous points are intentional, please clarify in the question what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi! The thing is that when I pass different test data to curve_fit it fits differently with different RMSE and R2. So what I did is: generate for example 100 different test sets of data and fit the curve_fit, then I choose the model with lowest RMSE and R2 closest to 1. So, an idea came to my mind: not use 100 different loops but try to use minimize which tries to find parameters of polynomial with lowest RMSE.                   The general idea is to fit my x1 and x2 in some f(x1,x2). Currently I use LinearRegression from sklearn.linear_model. But I'm not very satisfied with the results.